# How to add single quotes in string php?

Tags: php

I have `$a = "6,9,13,1"`

I want to change it to `$a = "'6','9','13','1'"`

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: neither version is valid php, and never will be. maybe you want to split your string into an array?

Comment: Both versions (you have and you want) have syntax errors. Best option, split into array and add the quotes. Or is this a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$a` is a string and you want to change numbers that way, you can use this code:

```
$a = preg_replace("/\d+/", "'$0'", $a);
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't have that in your source code, you can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), like so:

```
$a = '6,9,13,1';
$a = "'" . implode("','", explode(',', $a)) . "'";
```

---

If it's just a string in your code, you have two options..

Use a different quote:

```
$a = "'6','9','13','1'";
```

Escape the quotes:

```
$a = '\'6\',\'9\',\'13\',\'1\'';
```

*The first option is cleaner.* The second option is just to show that it's still possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming your variable have
`$a = "6,9,13,1";`

You can do something like that

```
$a = implode(",", array_map(function ($item) {
    return "'{$item}'";
}, explode(',', $a)));
```

Comment: Love the answer :)